# Eslint complaining about absolute import

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Eslint is complaining about absolute imports, although it does work perfectly in react. I am using VSCODE.
[image]

I added src to the eslintrc file:

```
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": [
          "src" <---------------------
        ],
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".jsx"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

and i also added `src` to the jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Technically, it all works, but still vscode complains about all absolute imports